# Unstated store based React Navigation causing warning

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, unstated

I'm using react-navigation and Unstated in my react native project.

I have a situation where I would like use:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("App")
```

after successfully signing in.

Problem is I don't want it done directly from a function assigned to a submit button.  I want to navigate based upon a global Unstated store.

However, it means that I would need to use a conditional INSIDE of the `Subscribe` wrapper.  That is what leads to the dreaded `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render').`

```js
  render() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    return (
      <Subscribe to={[MainStore]}>
        {({ auth: { state, testLogin } }) => {
          if (state.isAuthenticated) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
            return null;
          }
          console.log("rendering AuthScreen");
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <TextInput
                label="Username"
                onChangeText={this.setUsername}
                value={username}
                style={styles.input}
              />
              <TextInput
                label="Password"
                onChangeText={this.setPassword}
                value={password}
                style={styles.input}
              />
              {state.error && (
                <Text style={styles.error}>{state.error.message}</Text>
              )}
              <Button
                onPress={() => testLogin({ username, password })}
                color="#000"
                style={styles.button}
              >
                Sign in!
              </Button>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      </Subscribe>
    );
```

It works.  But what's the correct way to do it?
I don't have access to `MainStore` outside of `Subscribe` and therefore outside of `render`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found a better solution.
I created an HOC that I call now on any Component, functional or not, that requires access to the store.  That give me access to the store's state and functions all in props.  This means, I am free to use the component as it was intended, hooks and all.

Here's what it looks like:

WithUnstated.js

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Subscribe } from "unstated";

import MainStore from "../store/Main";

const withUnstated = (
  WrappedComponent,
  Stores = [MainStore],
  navigationOptions
) =>
  class extends PureComponent {
    static navigationOptions = navigationOptions;

    render() {
      return (
        <Subscribe to={Stores}>
          {(...stores) => {
            const allStores = stores.reduce(
              // { ...v } to force the WrappedComponent to rerender
              (acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v.displayName]: { ...v } }),
              {}
            );
            return <WrappedComponent {...allStores} {...this.props} />;
          }}
        </Subscribe>
      );
    }
  };

export default withUnstated;
```

Used like so in this Header example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

import styles from "./styles";

import { states } from "../../services/data";
import withUnstated from "../../components/WithUnstated";
import MainStore from "../../store/Main";

const Header = ({
  MainStore: {
    state: { vehicle }
  }
}) => (
  <View style={styles.plateInfo}>
    <Text style={styles.plateTop}>{vehicle.plate}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.plateBottom}>{states[vehicle.state]}</Text>
  </View>
);

export default withUnstated(Header, [MainStore]);
```

So now you don't need to create a million wrapper components for all the times you need your store available outside of your render function.
As, as an added goodie, the HOC accepts an array of stores making it completely plug and play.  AND - it works with your navigationOptions!

Just remember to add displayName to your stores (ES-Lint prompts you to anyway).

This is what a simple store looks like:

```js
import { Container } from "unstated";

class NotificationStore extends Container {
  state = {
    notifications: [],
    showNotifications: false
  };

  displayName = "NotificationStore";

  setState = payload => {
    console.log("notification store payload: ", payload);
    super.setState(payload);
  };

  setStateProps = payload => this.setState(payload);
}

export default NotificationStore;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the react-navigation patterns but you could use a wrapper around this component which subscribes to 'MainStore' and pass it down to this component as a prop. That way you'll have access to 'MainStore' outside the render method.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to avoid that.  I was hoping for a clean solution like react-router where I could use <Redirect>.

Comment: If no one comes up with a better solution, I'll choose this as the answer.  Thanks again!